# Django CSRF cookie not set error if there is cookie value starting with square brackets '['

Tags: python, django, cookies, csrf, django-csrf

I have a django site that is hosted on xyz.mysite.com. Parent site mysite.com which I do not own or control sets up a cookie with value `[XX]v3|[XXX]`. This causes my site to return the error `CSRF cookie not set.` This happened because django/middleware/csrf.py `csrf_token` value is set to none when the user tries to log in.

If I delete the square braces from the the cookie value set by mysite.com it works fine.

Any idea how to avoid this issue. I am using django 1.5.12 which I cannot upgrade.

Comment: Please keep in mind that 1.5 is an unsupported branch. It would be wise to either upgrade to 1.6 or downgrade (!) to 1.4.

Comment: Looks like its a python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue22931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a python 2.7.9 bug. It is fixed in 2.7.10  https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/2a7b0e145945